# how to free a CPU buffer defined in halide

Tags: cpu, halide

my projec used the buffer both in GPU and CPU.

code are similar like this:

```
xxx = HalideBuffer_n(width, heght, 1); // buffer in CPU
xxx.device_malloc(device); // buffer in GPU
PS: using HalideBuffer_n = Halide::Runtime::Buffer<uint8_t, 3>
```

i can use

```
 xxx.device_free();
```

to free the buffer in GPU. 
but which API can i choose to free the buffer in CPU？

i have used such as free or deallocate, but it seems dont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Halide::Buffer is a shared pointer to the underlying allocation. xxx.deallocate() drops the reference to it. If this is the only copy of that HalideBuffer_n object then it will free the underlying memory too. If it's not freeing it means that another copy of that HalideBuffer_n object exists somewhere.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  it seems like i dont need to free this buffer by myself in my project. it will handle it automatically.  i have figure out this problem.  thank you and wish you have a good day~ @Andrew Adams